# Protractor functional test cannot load unsafe http javascript

Tags: npm, protractor, functional-testing

So I wrote a bookmarklet and want to do some functional testing, I used Protractor and I was able to inject my bookmarklet javascript file to it. However since it is hosted locally it is not HTTPS. When I run the test although the js file is injected, I got

> VM122:17 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxxx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://localhost:8000/content.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Since the browser is newly created every time the test runs I can't set the 'load unsafe script option' for testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start chromedriver with extra arguments in your Protractor configuration.

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: "chrome",
    chromeOptions: {
        args: [
            "--allow-running-insecure-content"
        ]
    }
}
```

For a full list of chromedriver arguments, see:

- http://www.assertselenium.com/java/list-of-chrome-driver-command-line-arguments/
- https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities